# When to use UIPageViewController over UICollectionViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I want to implement a paginating mechanism to view images like a carousel or a gallery where the user just swipes to view the next image.

My requirements are that each page that the image is displayed in with an incoming url from a previous view controller's `prepare segue` statement. And that these images can be zoomed in if user intends to.
Also don't expect pages of more than 10 before before the user returns back to main view and selects on another cell to load another page view controller of several newer pages than the previous.

From what I understand so far, I can only imagine the following hierarchies

Using page view controller:

```
Hierarchy: 
- page view controller // controls which page can be seen
-- scroll view controller // allows image to be zoomed in and out
--- image view // image is set through kingfisher and is cached
-- page view controller indicator // indicator of page index
```

Using collection view controller: but not entirely sure if this is correct.

```
Hierarchy: 
- collection view controller // controls which page can be seen
-- collection view cell // container of scroll view with image view 
--- scroll view controller // allows image to be zoomed in and out
---- image view // image is set through kingfisher and is cached
-- page view controller indicator // indicator of page index
```

However, I'm running into a problem of whether to use a `page view controller` or a `collection view controller` and page per cell as the user swipes.

Also it would seem as though pagination with a page view controller needs to load all the necessary content view controllers at the start when it is called... Not loading when each time a scroll gesture is called... Is this a limitation of page view controller?

I'd like to know what are some tradeoffs and benefits of using each one of these approaches.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI - if you want to save some effort, there are plenty of existing third party libraries for this. Search GitHub.